# Backbone models, JSON and HTML Forms

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Backbone models `.get()` and `.set()` routines are fine if your values are simple attributes.  I have inherited an app however where the values are also JSON objects.

i.e. `model.get("key")` returns

```
{start:
    {top:5, bottom:6}, 
    end:{...}
 }
```

etc.  Setting any of these values using `.set()` is a PITA because you have to pull out the old value, make the change you want, and punt it back in again.  i.e. if I want `bottom` = 7, you can't just do `.set("start.bottom",7)`.  I need to do something like:

```
var tempValue = model.get("start");
tempValue.bottom = 7;
model.set("start",tempValue)
```

Models have an attributes property, where you *can* do `model.attributes.start.bottom = 7`.  Now this presumably doesn't fire any event handlers, because looking at the Backbone code, that is done in `set`.

So two questions:

- If I don't need the change handlers to fire, is there anything wrong
  with setting attributes directly.
- Is there anyway of firing the
  change handlers manually after setting attributes?

The Backbone changelog says - *"The Model#change method has been removed, as delayed attribute changes are no longer available"* -but I'm not entirely sure why this would be.  It sounds useful.

Related to this: I'm also trying to parse a HTML form into the model.  I've been trying to use ModelBinder, but it can't handle nested JSON.  e.g. `<input type="text" name="start.top">`

Edit:
I've just realised you can do `model.set({})` with an object.  e.g. `model.set({start :{top:7}});` but it's a bit clunky

Answer (score 2):

> 1. If I don't need the change handlers to fire, is there anything wrong with setting attributes directly.

I think that this may answer your question:
[Backbone.js get and set nested object attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351271/backbone-js-get-and-set-nested-object-attribute)

> 2. Is there anyway of firing the change handlers manually after setting attributes?

The `set` method (without silent option) triggers 2 events: "change" and "change:attributeName".

If you need it, you can trigger them manually by invoking:

```
model.trigger("change change:attributeName")
```