# Support for Dot Notation in Backbone Models

Tags: backbone.js

How to get support for dot notation/nested objects in backbone model. The plugins that are available are buggy and wondering if backbone would ever support

```
person = { name : {first: 'hon',last:'son'}}
model = new Backbone.Model(person)
model.get('name.first')
model.set('name.first','bon')
```

Comment: Did you try this model.get('name').first ?

Comment: I can do that..but setting would not trigger a change..nor can I bind to listen for change in attributes of object..

Comment: I think there is already a post that answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351271/backbone-js-get-and-set-nested-object-attribute

Answer (score 2):

There are two plugins to get the job done:

- [Backbone Nested](https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested)
- [Backbone Deep Model](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model)

Both handle getting and setting attributes and change events for dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

I did that if  i were you:

```
var nameObj = model.get('name')
nameObj.first = bon
model.set('name', nameObj)
```