# BackboneJS How to get nested attributes of model

Tags: backbone.js

My Backbone Model is fetching data from an API as JSON

the structure is like:

```
 releases
     tracks
        length
```

Now I specifically want to the lenght of a track. How do achieve that?

I tried to do

```
afterRender: function(){
   this.model.get('releases.tracks.length');
   console.log(track);
}
```

but that didnt work, gives me 'undefined'

please help

Comment: This has been asked a number of times e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351271/backbone-js-get-and-set-nested-object-attribute. To sum up you can do `this.model.get('releases').tracks.length` though in some cases you might want to consider nested models.

Comment: Ok sorry, but this gives me `Cannot read property 'lenght' of undefined `...

Comment: this is because either tracks is undefined or not an array, or because you spelled `length` as `lenght` :)